# I want to remove the space and special characters between the a records,

Tags: talend

Actual Record

"102","kal12 3@ ","18009","10009","29","HR","del"

What I want (Expecting record)

"102","kal123","18009","10009","29","HR","del"

For above scenario,If you see the record "kal12 3@" which is actual record but I want transform the record as like "kal123" I were used "StringHandling.CHANGE("hello world!","world","guy")" function for remove the special characters and for space removing used StringHandling.TRIM(" hellow world! ")
But I want to remove the space and special characters at a time,so can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

I am Using Talend open studio

Thanks& Regards,
Naresh

Answer (score 1):

Supposing the field name is row1.myField, try this in a tMap:
`row1.myField.replaceAll("[@ ]", "")`
You just have to include each character you want to remove from row1.myField between the square brackets.
Hope this helps.

TRF

Comment: #TRF dear it's very helpful for me and I am very thankful to you.

Comment: Great! Don't hesitate to mark you question as solved ;)